# Family of $A^2=I$

Tags: matrices, number-theory

Let $A$ be $2×2$ matrix such that their elements are Integer, inverse matrix exits and $A^2=E$. I'm thinking about decomposing $A$ into family by regarding $A$ as a family of $T^{-1}AT$.

I wonder how many families are there? 
I expect there  are only $4$ families ,
$\begin{bmatrix} ±1 & 0 \\ 0 & ±1 \end{bmatrix}$.

But how to prove that?

By Cayley-Hamilton theorem ,$1+tr(A)+det(A)=0$

By the existence of inverse matrix, $det(A)=±1$

Now I came to a deadlock.

Comment: You have only named three families, since $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ are conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A^2=E$, $A$ is invertible. It is also *diagonalizable*, because otherwise its Jordan form over $\Bbb{C}$ would be
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 \cr 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix},
$$
with $\lambda=\pm 1$. But then $J$ has infinite order, hence $A$ too, a contradiction to $A^2=E$.  So $A$ is diagonalizable, i.e.,
$$
TAT^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \cr 0 & \mu\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then we obtain
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \lambda^2 & 0 \cr 0 & \mu^2\end{pmatrix}=(TAT^{-1})^2=TA^2T^{-1}=TET^{-1}=E,
$$
so that $\lambda^2=\mu^2=\pm 1$. Over the integers there are exactly the four possibilities you have obtained. Two of them are still conjugated.

Comment: The story is more complicated if you require $T$ and $T^{-1}$ to have integer entries, though.  The question was unclear about whether just $A$ or all the matrices were supposed to have integer entries.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: every eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of the minimal polynomial of $A$, which divides $x^2-1$.